# What all servers do I need to install to deploy and run my PHP web app, if I don't want to use the XAMPP package?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, lampp

For web development where I use PHP on the backend, I have always used XAMPP (Windows) or LAMPP (Ubuntu).

Now I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and for some reason, I can not use an LAMPP package. So my question is what independent servers do I need to install?

I know that I need to install PHP, and I also know that I will need to install MySQL database Server if my application uses MySQL database.

But what else do I need to install, apart from PHP 7.1 and MySQL database server?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04 is probably helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAMPP is short for:

- Linux
- Apache
- MySQL
- PHP
- Perl

So if you are developing Web Applications I would say that you are fine with Apache, MySQL and PHP. There might be some other modules (e.g. for SEO reasons like mod_rewrite) but those could be easily installed later one.